# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Issue from Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I am attempting to run a java file from Command Prompt. When I run the program in NetBeans IDE, it works fine. Unfortunately, I need to be able to run it from Command Prompt. I have two classes. I will include all the code in case it is relevant. I looked for posts with this issue, but I did not see anything that seemed to solve my problem. When explaining things, please do so as if talking to somebody who knows little about any of this because that is the case.

```js
package projectbeng;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DataRecover {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        //Create a Scanner for the user
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter file name to process: ");
        File fileName = new File(sc.nextLine() + ".txt"); //Do not include the .txt extension
        
        if(!fileName.exists()){ //does not exist
            throw new IOException("File \"" + fileName + "\" not found.");
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nProcessing file: " + fileName + "\n----------------------------------------");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        int lineCount = 0; //assumes file does not end with a new line character
        int tripleLineCount = 0;
        int tripleCount = 0;
        String line = "";
            
        //Read data from file
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //has another line in the file
            lineCount++;
            if(!line.equals("")) { //is not a blank line
                Triple triples = extractTriples(line);
                if(triples.getHasTriple()) { //line contains triples
                    System.out.println(triples.getTriples());
                    tripleLineCount++;
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < triples.getTriples().length(); j++) {
                    if(triples.getTriples().charAt(j) == '(') tripleCount++;
                }
            }
        }
            
        //prints out the summary of the file
        System.out.println("\nSummary\n----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total lines:              " + lineCount);
        System.out.println("Lines containing triples: " + tripleLineCount);
        System.out.println("Total number of triples:  " + tripleCount);  
    }
    
    /*Given a string, returns a Triple with a string containing the triples (if any) and a boolean stating whether
    or not it contains a triple.
    
    Assumptions:
    1.) If a '-' sign is found, it has been added. If preceeding a number (for example -32), the number is 32 where
        the '-' sign is simply garbage.
    2.) If a '.' is found in a number (for example 2.32), the potential integers are 2 and 32 where the '.' is
        garbage.
    3.) For part c, if the first valid character found is a letter, this will always be the real triple. It does not
        matter whether or not it is part of a word (for example, if it comes across "Dog a", 'D' will be the triple.)
    4.) The strings "<null>", "<cr>", "<lf>", and "<eof>" as well as multi-digit numbers (ex. 32) count as single
        characters. Thus, they cannot be broken up (no garbage in between the characters).
    */

    static Triple extractTriples(String str) {     
        /*Grammar:
        Triple is in form (a,b,c) where a is either a non-negative integer or the string "<null>", b is a
            non-negative integer where b <= a (b must be 0 if a is <null>), and c is either an individual letter 
            (upper or lower case), period, colon, semicolon, or one of the three strings "<cr>", "<lf>", or "<eof>".
        state == 0 ==> needs left parenthesis
        state == 1 ==> needs right parenthesis
        state == 2 ==> needs comma
        state == 3 ==> needs a
        state == 4 ==> needs b
        state == 5 ==> needs c
        */
        int state = 0;
        int a = -1;
        int b = -1;
        String triples = "";
        String tempTriples = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == '.' || str.charAt(i) == ':' || str.charAt(i) == ';' || str.charAt(i) == '<' ||
                    (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (str.charAt(i) >= 'A' && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z')
                    || (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') || str.charAt(i) == ',' ||
                    str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if(state == 0) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) == '(') {
                        tempTriples = str.substring(i, i+1);
                        state = 3;
                    }
                }else if(state == 1) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) == ')') {
                        triples = triples + tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1) + "  ";
                        tempTriples = "";
                        state = 0;
                        a = -1;
                        b = -1;
                    }
                }else if(state == 2) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) == ',') {
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1);
                        if(b != -1) state = 5;
                        else state = 4;
                    }
                }else if(state == 3) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                        int j = i;
                        while(j < str.length() && str.charAt(j) >= '0' && str.charAt(j) <= '9') j++;
                        a = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
                        i = j - 1;
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + a;
                        state = 2;
                    }else if(str.length() > i + 5 && str.substring(i, i+6).equals("<null>")) {
                        a = 0;
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, str.indexOf(">", i)+1);
                        i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                        state = 2;
                    }
                }else if(state == 4) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                        int j = i;
                        while(j < str.length() && str.charAt(j) >= '0' && str.charAt(j) <= '9') j++;
                        b = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j));
                        i = j - 1;
                        if(b <= a) {
                            tempTriples = tempTriples + b;
                            state = 2;
                        }else b = -1;
                    }
                }else if(state == 5) {
                    if(str.charAt(i) == '.' || str.charAt(i) == ':'||(str.charAt(i) <= 'z' && str.charAt(i) >= 'a')
                            || str.charAt(i) == ';' || (str.charAt(i) <= 'Z' && str.charAt(i) >= 'A')) {
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, i+1);
                        state = 1;
                    }else if((str.length() > i + 4 && str.substring(i, i+5).equals("<eof>")) ||
                            (str.length() > i + 3 && (str.substring(i, i+4).equals("<cr>") ||
                            str.substring(i, i+4).equals("<lf>")))) {
                        tempTriples = tempTriples + str.substring(i, str.indexOf(">", i)+1);
                        i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                        state = 1;
                    }else if(str.length() > i + 5 && str.substring(i, i+6).equals("<null>")) {
                        i = str.indexOf(">", i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Triple triple = new Triple(true, triples);
        if(triples.equals("")) triple.setHasTriple(false); //does not contain a triple
        return triple;
    }
    
}
```

```js
package projectbeng;
class Triple {
    boolean hasTriple = this.hasTriple;
    String triple = this.triple;
    
    //creates a new Triple
    Triple(boolean newHasTriple, String newTriple){
        this.hasTriple = newHasTriple;
        this.triple = newTriple;
    }
     //returns whether or not Triple contains any triples
    boolean getHasTriple() {
        return hasTriple;
    }
    
    //returns the triples in Triple
    String getTriples() {
        return triple;
    }
    
    //changes the state of whether a Triple contains triples
    void setHasTriple(boolean newHasTriple){
        this.hasTriple = newHasTriple;
    }
}
```

Now, I run command prompt, and I run it as shown in the picture. As can also be seen, the CLASS files for DataRecover and Triple are created.

[Screenshot of Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RstAq.png)

Now, what I did was I created the folder ProjectBenG in my C drive. I placed my DataRecover.java and Triple.java files in this folder. After that, I ran the Command Prompt. I am curious what I need to do in order to run DataRecover. Also, you can see in the folder a file "triplestest.txt". I would like this to be the file that is processed by DataRecover in my code. I have not gotten that far yet, but if there is something specific I need to do in order for that to work as well, I would appreciate that information

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Comment: It is better to spend an hour NOW to learn about JAR-packages and how to make them with Netbeans, than waste a lot of time with javac. With larger applications separate .class files are unusable anyway. ( Probably you should place classes to directory projectbeng, also setup java parameter -cp  )

Comment: @OlegGritsak I am familiar with using NetBeans. The issue is, someone needs to use the program I wrote. They do not want to use NetBeans. Instead, they want to run it through Command Prompt. As for your comment, I have the classes saved into the folder "projectbeng". I tried using the parameter -cp, but it did not seem to help.

Comment: It is better to spend an hour NOW to learn about JAR-packages. Then your "someone" will run you program like java -jar anyname.jar without need of Netbeans. And whole application will be in single JAR-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is your project structure.

You have two options that I know of.

1) Remove the two package declarations at the top of each file. Then, as you have, compile with

> $javac *.java
>
> $java DataRecover

2) Keep the package in tact and put it inside a folder named [package name] (in your case projectbeng). Then comile and run from parent directory.

> $mkdir projectbeng
>
> $cd projectbeng
>
> $javac *.java
>
> $cd ..
>
> $java projectbeng.DataRecover

Keep in mind if youre running windows the directory/folder management will be slightly different. Let me know how it goes.

As others have said you may want to learn about making jar files to use and distribute. I'm guessing your prof likes it simple for marking his assignments though (mine did too). Anyways... this link might help http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Edit: looking at your screenshot it seems you already have the folder made, try moving up one directory and running

> $java projectbeng.DataRecover

Comment: Thank you for much for the help! I was able to successfully do what I was attempting. I also looked into the link you sent me. It made things much easier. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If I helped you out, accept the answer. It would help me out.